# Pandas Dynamic Stack

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, dataframe

Given the following data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c','d'],
                   'bar':['e','f','g','h'],
                       0:['i','j','k',np.nan],
                       1:['m',np.nan,'o','p']})
df=df[['foo','bar',0,1]]
df

    foo   bar    0      1
0   a     e      i      m
1   b     f      j     NaN
2   c     g      k      o
3   d     h     NaN     p
```

...which resulted from a previous procedure that produced columns `0` and `1` (and may have produced more or fewer columns than `0` and `1` depending on the data):
I want to somehow stack (if that's the correct term) the data so that each value of `0` and `1` (ignoring `NaN`s) produces a new row like this:

```
    foo bar
0   a   e
0   a   i
0   a   m
1   b   f
1   b   j
2   c   g
2   c   k
2   c   o
3   d   h
3   d   p
```

You probably noticed that the common field is `foo`. 
It will likely occur that there are more common fields in my actual data set.
Also, I'm not sure how important it is that the index values repeat in the end result across values of `foo`. As long as the data is correct, that's my main concern.

Update:
What if I have 2+ common fields like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['a','a','b','b'],
                   'foo2':['a2','b2','c2','d2'],
                   'bar':['e','f','g','h'],
                       0:['i','j','k',np.nan],
                       1:['m',np.nan,'o','p']})
df=df[['foo','foo2','bar',0,1]]
df

    foo     foo2    bar     0   1
0   a       a2      e     i     m
1   a       b2      f     j     NaN
2   b       c2      g     k     o
3   b       d2      h     NaN   p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df.set_index('foo').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='bar')
  foo bar
0   a   e
1   a   i
2   a   m
3   b   f
4   b   j
5   c   g
6   c   k
7   c   o
8   d   h
9   d   p
```

If you need index, use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
print pd.melt(df.reset_index(), 
              id_vars=['index', 'foo'], 
              value_vars=['bar', 0, 1],
              value_name='bar')
        .sort_values('index')
        .set_index('index', drop=True)
        .dropna()
        .drop('variable', axis=1)
        .rename_axis(None)

  foo bar
0   a   e
0   a   i
0   a   m
1   b   f
1   b   j
2   c   g
2   c   k
2   c   o
3   d   h
3   d   p
```

Or use not well known `lreshape`:

```
print pd.lreshape(df.reset_index(), {'bar': ['bar', 0, 1]})
        .sort_values('index')
        .set_index('index', drop=True)
        .rename_axis(None)

  foo bar
0   a   e
0   a   i
0   a   m
1   b   f
1   b   j
2   c   g
2   c   k
2   c   o
3   d   h
3   d   p
```

Comment: You are incredible! How do you know all this stuff?

Comment: `Index` is important ? Or you can use something similar as first solution with `stack`?

Comment: Index not important. I tried both  like this but no dice: print (df.set_index('foo','foo2').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='bar'))

Comment: Now I got it, I had to adjust the level value on reset_index to 2 like this:  print (df.set_index(['foo','foo2']).stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index(name='bar'))

Comment: Sorry, I think you need columns `foo` and `foo2` to one :) - And it is possible by `print df.set_index(['foo', 'foo2']).stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index(name='bar').set_index('bar').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='foo')`

Comment: My fault; I didn't explain it well. What I needed was for foo and foo2 to exist as columns, repeating for each appropriate instance of bar. So what I did worked for me.

Comment: No problem. I see error, but I think it is only typo.